# python: 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: python, string

I have gone through many similar posts here and there but non of them seem solve my problem. I have a method that searches for file path:

```
def getDumpFile(self):
        self.saveDump()
        dumpname = str(self.filename)+'-01.netxml'

        filepath = os.path.join('/some/path/to/file',dumpname)
        try:
            if os.path.exists(os.path.join('/some/path/to/file',dumpname)):
                logging.debug( "Filepath "+str(filepath) )
                return filepath
            else:
                logging.debug( "File Not Found" )
                return None
        except OSError as e:
            logging.debug( "File not created: "+str(e) )
            return None
```

and in the main function I call this function like this:

```
xmlfile = wscanner.getDumpFile()
```

and when I execute above code, it finds the correct path in `getDumpFile()` method but the server gives out exception:

```
Unexpected exception in wireless.views.attackAP with type <type 'exceptions.TypeError'> and error 'str' object is not callable
```

I really don't know why passing the `filepath` to `xmlfile` variable(which I believe is never initiated before)could cause error,please help. Thanks.

Edit: It is actually the code `xmlfile = wscanner.getDumpFile()` that gives out error, but I don't know why. Comment out this line would get rid of the error, but I need this path later on.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback of your error.  You didn't even point us to the line the error occurs in.

Comment: did someone define a variable called str thats hiding the builtin? Coming from other languages, I've done this on accident a few times.

Comment: my guess, but without seeing more code it's just a guess - you need to return an actual file reference object, or some other object that has methods, and not the file name.

Comment: -0 on this question since we don't have a traceback.  Eventually it will be a -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why I enjoy StackOverflow -- it causes you to really plunge deeper.

The last poster is 100% correct. I wrote a quick class to demo the problem.  If I had to go on what we know from the poster, I'd suggest to take a closer look at references to getDumpFile, to ensure someone is not accidentally assigning a string value to it:

```
class MyClass:
    def getDumpFile(self):
        pass

myclass = MyClass()
myclass.getDumpFile = 'hello world'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of 'non-pythonic' stuff going on in this module. But let's ignore that for a moment.

You're saying the error message comes from calling method:

```
xmlfile = wscanner.getDumpFile()
```

If I had to guess, I'd say 'wscanner' is not defined how you think it is -- and specifically, the python interpreter thinks it's a string.

Try adding this call right before the call to getDumpFile()

```
print type(wscanner)
```

See what it shows.

Comment: If `wscanner` was a string you'd get an AttributeError, not a TypeError.